# laravel inner join 3 table

Tags: php, laravel

users

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | aaa |
| 2 | bbb |
| 3 | cccc |

diffacts

| user_id | created_date | duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 25.02.2022 | 4 |
| 1 | 25.02.2022 | 3 |
| 2 | 24.02.2022 | 5 |

offdays

| user_id | created_date | duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 25.02.2022 | 2 |
| 3 | 24.02.2022 | 5 |

output

| name | duration(diffacts) | duration(offdays) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 7 | 0 |
| bbb | 5 | 2 |
| cccc | 0 | 5 |

Comment: Didn't understood what you want to ask?

Comment: please add more information.

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear. if you are looking for join operation using three tables it will help.

```
DoctorCategory::    
join('doctors','doctors.id','=','doctor_categories.doctor_id')    
->join('users','doctors.user_id','=','users.id')    
->where('doctor_categories.category_id',$request->id)    
->select('doctors.id','users.first_name','users.last_name')->get();
```

- table 1 = doctor_categories (DoctorCategory :- model name)
- table 2 = doctors
- table 3 = users